# How to build a personal cluster?

Tags: linux, debian, cluster

I have a debian server running some services (mail, web, git, mysql...). But it is alone, meaning that if it breaks, I have to repair it to access my services.

I'd like to put a second server so that if the first one dies the second one is automatically ready to work. I don't want any of this servers to be a master and the other one a slave. The idea is to prevent hardware failure from any of the two servers.

I found lots of info about how to create some big clusters, but I haven't found any thing that imply only two servers.

Comment: A redundant server is not a cluster, you know ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The idea is to prevent hardware failure from any of the two servers.

Yeah. When you find a way to pßrevent hardware failures, tell the manufacturers and get rich. Clusters / Redundant servers never are there to prevent failures, but to mitigate them - i.e. neutralize their impact. The hardware still fails.

> I don't want any of this servers to be a master and the other one a slave.

So you look for a master/master mail server? Have fun trying to find that. In the MS world, Exchange can do that - nearly. I know of no other server doing it. THe standard approach is to have a master/slave setup.

> I found lots of info about how to create some big clusters, but I haven't found any thing 
>   that imply only two servers.

Because you are the only one calling that a cluster. What you look for is a redunant server. Clusters come in 2 scenarios: HPC clusters (distribute work), in which case 2 nodes is a very degenerate case (we talk of hundreds, thousands, tens of thousands of nodes) and availability / application clusters, like MS Cluster Service or Oracle RAC. The later often is software specific - unless you run for a simple failover (mail server restarts on server 2) and then you have shared storage requirements.

For example MySQL - you can not do that.You may get away with replication, but replication is - application specific. If the application is not written for replication, master/master replication will not work, only master/slave will. Because when writing the application you must make sure you have proper unique ID's, handle deletes in a way that ALWAYS works nice etc.